# Error "TypeError context must be a dict rather than Context" on Django 1.11

Tags: python, django

I received a message TypeError context must be a dict rather than Context. But don't know how to fix it.

```
def comment(request,id):
    if id:
        r = Restaurant.objects.get(id=id)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/restaurants_list/")
    if request.POST:
        visitor = request.POST['visitor']
        content = request.POST['content']
        email = request.POST['email']
        date_time = timezone.localtime(timezone())
        Comment.objects.create(
            visitor=visitor,
            email=email,
            content=content,
            date_time=date_time,
            restaurant=r
        )
    return render_to_response('comments.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see the description of [`context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#optional-arguments) argument:

> A dictionary of values to add to the template context. By default, this is an empty dictionary. If a value in the dictionary is callable, the view will call it just before rendering the template.

Change your line:

```
return render_to_response('comments.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))
```

To:

```
return render_to_response('comments.html', context=locals())
```